# Next.JS: Does SSR in dynamic content improves performace?

Tags: performance, next.js, server-side-rendering

Imagine two approches:

1. when the component mounts in the client, it will fetch dynamic data from the server.
2. SSR serves the component's dynamic data.

What are the performance gains we get in the second approach?

In the second approach, will the server retrieve the javascript bundle and the dynamic data on a single HTTP connection? If so, is this performance gain relevant? Is there any other factor that contributes to the second approach being worst or better in terms of performance?